# php-fpm70 memory usage while using my own plugin in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm newbie in this and want to show IPsuit 4 latest topic in my website that works with wordpress.

so when I used following code and sql query, php used too much memory and run many process:

```
  function ipslatest_main()
  {
    $db_user = get_option('ipslatest_db_user');
    $db_name = get_option('ipslatest_db_name');
    $db_pass = get_option('ipslatest_db_pw');
    $db_host = get_option('ipslatest_db_host');
    $prefix = get_option('ipslatest_db_prefix');
    $url = get_option('ipslatest_url');
    $limit = get_option('ipslatest_limit');
    $title = get_option('ipslatest_title');
    $width = get_option('ipslatest_width');
    $direction = get_option('ipslatest_direction');
    $translations = array('Ù…ÙˆØ¶ÙˆØ¹','Ø¨Ø§Ø²Ø¯ÙŠØ¯','Ù¾Ø§Ø³Ø®','Ø§Ø±Ø³Ø§Ù„ Ú©Ù†Ù†Ø¯Ù‡');
     $db = new wpdb( $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name,$db_host );
  $q = $db->get_results( 'SELECT topic_firstpost,starter_name FROM '.$prefix.'forums_topics ORDER BY tid DESC LIMIT '.$limit );
  echo '<div id="ipslatest-mainTitle" style="width:'.$width.'">'.$title.$position.'</div>';
  echo '<table id="ipslatestTopics"  border=0 style="padding:10px;width:'.$width.'">';
    echo '<tr><td class="ipslatest-row-views">'.$translations[2].'</td><td class="ipslatest-row-answers">'.$translations[1].'</td><td class="ipslatest-row-sender">'.$translations[3].'</td><td class="ipslatest-row-title">'.$translations[0].'</td> </tr>';
    if (is_array($q) || is_object($q))
    {
        foreach ($q as $key => $row) {
          $topicDetails = $db->get_row('SELECT title,tid,views,posts FROM '.$prefix.'forums_topics WHERE tid='.$row->topic_firstpost);
          $userMemberID = $db->get_row('SELECT member_group_id FROM '.$prefix."core_members WHERE name='".$row->starter_name."'");
          $userShowingData = $db->get_row('SELECT prefix,suffix FROM '.$prefix.'core_groups WHERE g_id='.$userMemberID->member_group_id);
          echo '<tr id="ipstopic"> <td class="ipslatest-row-views-content"> <span>'.$topicDetails->views.' </span></td> <td class="ipslatest-row-answers-content"><span>'.($topicDetails->posts - 1).'</span></td> <td id="ipslatest-row-sender-content">'.$userShowingData->prefix.$row->starter_name.$userShowingData->suffix.'</td> <td class="ipsTitle"> <a rel="follow" href="'.$url.'topic/'.$topicDetails->tid.'-'.strtolower(str_replace(" ","-",$topicDetails->title)).'">'. strip_tags($topicDetails->title) .' </a> </td> </tr>';
        }
    }
  echo '</table>';
}
```

of course this is part of my code but can you help me where is the problem?
I'm using php 7.0.26 and MariaDB 10.1.29.

Don't give me negative point please. I'm new in this. :(

thanks.

Comment: How large is $q? Who decides how much memory is too much? Read about memory management in Unix. The more memory is used the better for the OS.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out parts of your code to see which line is using "too much memory"? By the way, what does that mean in numbers?

Comment: when i saw this last time, it was 14 gigabyte usage in services monitoring. at first it was 2 gigabyte but after a while it turn to 14 gig! I thing foreach loop do this code over and over times. and this makes cause the problem :|

Comment: now you can see my entire function.